# Issue with Gradle task to write file

Tags: gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am developing an Android application where I have a directory of JSON files and I want to create a gradle task that will combine all these files into a single JSON file.

This is the gradle task I have so far but does not create the file:

```
// Task that combines all JSON files in ../libraries into src/main/res/raw/libraries.json
task combineJSonFiles {
    String content = ""
    FileTree tree = fileTree(dir: '../libraries', include: '**/*.json')
    tree.each {File file ->
        content += file.getText()
    }

    println "[" + content.substring(0, content.length()-1) + "]" // prints out the correct contents
    File libraries = file("../app/src/main/res/raw/libraries.json")
    println libraries.getProperties()
}
```

I print out the properties and I am not sure why these are the property values:

```
{directory=false, canonicalFile=/Users/michaelcarrano/AndroidStudioProjects/detective_droid/app/src/main/res/raw/libraries.json, file=false, freeSpace=0, canonicalPath=/Users/michaelcarrano/AndroidStudioProjects/detective_droid/app/src/main/res/raw/libraries.json, usableSpace=0, hidden=false, totalSpace=0, path=/Users/michaelcarrano/AndroidStudioProjects/detective_droid/app/src/main/res/raw/libraries.json, name=libraries.json, prefixLength=1, absolute=true, class=class java.io.File, parentFile=/Users/michaelcarrano/AndroidStudioProjects/detective_droid/app/src/main/res/raw, absolutePath=/Users/michaelcarrano/AndroidStudioProjects/detective_droid/app/src/main/res/raw/libraries.json, absoluteFile=/Users/michaelcarrano/AndroidStudioProjects/detective_droid/app/src/main/res/raw/libraries.json, parent=/Users/michaelcarrano/AndroidStudioProjects/detective_droid/app/src/main/res/raw}
```

Any help is appreciated as I have not seemed to figure this out even after reading the documentation. http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/working_with_files.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating an instance of java.io.File in Groovy/Java does not create the file on disk. You will need to write something to it. Check out this [tutorial](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com.au/2009/08/groovy-goodness-working-with-files.html) for working with files in Groovy.

Also you have put your task implementation in a task configuration block, rather than a task action. This means your code will not be running when you are expecting - it will run every time you run gradle rather than when you run this task. You need to put your code in a `doLast` block

Comment: Thanks! I finally got it to work but I could have sworn I tried the working way already. As for this task, I do want it to run each time I run Gradle just to be sure I have the most up to date version of the file. Let me know if you think there is a better way to have the task run.

Comment: At present that code runs as part of the configuration phase of gradle and has nothing to do with the task running.

Comment: I'd advise putting your code in a doLast block and then using `dependsOn` to make sure the task runs when you want it to

Comment: Then, you might want to consider declaring the inputs and ouputs of your task so that it doesn't do unnecessary work if nothing has changed. Take a look at http://www.gradle.org/docs/2.0/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:up_to_date_checks

Answer (score 2):

I am just posting the code for the task that now works:

```
task combineJSonFiles {
    String content = ""
    FileTree tree = fileTree(dir: '../libraries', include: '**/*.json')
    tree.each {File file ->
        content += file.getText()
    }
    def libraries = new File("app/src/main/res/raw/libraries.json")
    libraries.text = "[" + content.substring(0, content.length()-1) + "]"
}
```

My issue was trying to use Java.io.File and having the wrong directory path set for my file.